# Get outlook contacts with photo using Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the list of outlook contacts using MS Graph api (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

It is possible to get contacts using the next query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Also I can get a photo for a particular contact using, for example:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/photo/$value

but how can I get the list of contacts with photo in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confusing `Contacts` and `Users`, these are two distinct entities. `Users` are Active Directory objects, `Contacts` are objects created by a user and stored in their Outlook mailbox. You fetch Contacts using the `/me/contacts` endpoint.

As to your question regarding photos. No, you cannot retrieve the photo inline with the contact list results. Photos must be queried separately due to the result having a different `content-type`. The list is returned as `application/json` while the image is returned as `image/{image-type}`.