# MS Graph API - using expand=photo when getting contacts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-contacts

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/{id}?$expand=photo
```

Should return a contact object with a field stating whether the contact has a photo or not

This was already kind of discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/contact-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901410/819355)
and the response was that this is not possible because "photo" has a binary response while the get contact endpoint returns a json.

**however** with contacts `profilePhoto` there are two separate endpoints:

```
GET /me/contacts/{id}/photo/$value
```

return the photo itself in binary stream

```
GET /me/contacts/{id}/photo
```

returns metadata of the contact's photo - this is extremely useful for figuring out if that contact has a photo or not

by the way, supplying the above "$expand" option doesn't fail the API call, it will add the following header to the json response:
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('myemail@example.com')/contacts(photo())/$entity",
however no field is added to the json object that could help us figure out if that contact has a photo or not.

**Some Background:**

There may be thousands of contacts in the account, if you want to list them all you don't need too many network calls as you can use:

```
/me/contacts/microsoft.graph.delta
```

with header: `Prefer=odata.maxpagesize=300`

but if you want to show photos of those contacts you can't do it for many contacts at once, if you use batches you can do up to 4 contacts at a time, which results in potentially thousands of API calls where most would probably return 404 since the contact doesn't have a photo.
Adding the photo existence field using the $expand would solve this and allow us to reduce our API calls dramatically

Another point to make me think this should have been a supported by the API - in the [JSON representation of a contact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/contact?view=graph-rest-1.0#json-representation) example it ends with:

```
"photo": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.profilePhoto" }
```

But when I get contacts from the API this field doesn't exist

Comment: You can vote for the request to return photo in select statement. Then you should be able to filter photo like this /me/contacts?$filter=photo eq null
 https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/graph-api-support-for-photos-property-in-select/idi-p/3003886

Comment: i voted for the feature request, however for my use case the better option would be to allow $expand to the get contacts request, this should be possible according to the get-contact API documentation

Answer (score 1):

So the unpopular answer is, as of today this is unsupported, you should upvote the feature.

This questions just doesn’t alphabet a good answer, at the moment…